# "Il cenno di silenzio", "il cenno del silenzio" o qualcos'altro?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, articles

Nella fotografia di questo [sito web](http://www.succedeoggi.it/2014/09/elogio-silenzio/) si vede Claudio Abbado che fa il cenno a cui si riferisce la mia domanda. Come si deve dire? Il Maestro fa il cenno *di* silenzio con il dito? Il Maestro fa il cenno *del* silenzio con il dito?

Comment: Io direi *Il Maestro fa cenno di fare silenzio*, ma probabilmente non è quello che tu stai chiedendo.

Comment: *Un cenno di silenzio*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma migliore con *cenno* è, secondo me,

> il maestro Abbado fa un cenno di silenzio

se il gesto è generico. Nel caso della fotografia

> il maestro Abbado fa il gesto del silenzio

Non è un cenno, ma un gesto ben preciso. Muovere la mano dall'alto in basso per chiedere meno rumore sarebbe un cenno. Mettere l'indice davanti alla bocca, almeno per gli italiani, è un gesto inequivocabile.

L'origine di *cenno* è una parola tardolatina che significa *l'atto di ammiccare*, mentre *gesto* viene da *gerere*, cioè *compiere* (fonte: dizionario Treccani). Sebbene simili, vedo in *gesto* qualcosa di più eloquente di un segno.

Comment: http://motivationalattitude.blogspot.com.es/2014/01/signum-harpocraticum-assenza-della.html

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?id=XUX8AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=%22il+gesto+del+silenzio%22+dito&source=bl&ots=T2ibhqh0iW&sig=AKSurfel05clGZZ8UAj_yF6TwqY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LIKRVKmhDYGtUcGBhDg&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22il%20gesto%20del%20silenzio%22%20dito&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Sono abbastanza certo si dica "cenno DI silenzio", anche se suona strano.

Answer (score 2):

"Il cenno **del** silenzio" significherebbe che esiste un cenno specifico usato per fare silenzio, un po' come "il segnale **della** partenza". Quindi, se proprio volessi usare quel costrutto e non un'altra frase come indicato nei commenti su, direi "il cenno **di** silenzio".

Answer (score 0):

*Il cenno del silenzio* se intendi propriamente quel particolare gesto, mentre *un cenno di silenzio* rappresenta un qualsiasi cenno effettuato per chiedere silenzio ed è molto meno specifico.
Insomma l'articolo determinativo specifica specificità, quindi, in questo caso, è proprio usare "del".